# Display only top result from mysql query?

Tags: mysql

How can I display only the top/largest percentage from this query?

```
select round((count(*)*100)/(select count(*) from test),1) as percent from test group by field1 order by percent desc
```

For example this is data received from the query:

[image]

What I want displayed on an HTML page from this query is this:

[image]

Comment: `LIMIT 1` your welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MySQL Limit!](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html)

```
select round((count(*)*100)/(select count(*) from test),1) as percent from test group by field1 order by percent desc LIMIT 1;
```