# MySQL get average of first 3 MAX values from Group

Tags: mysql

I've got those tables

```
table1: GROUPS  
grpID | name
--------------
1     | A
2     | B
3     | C
4     | D
5     | E

table2: USERS       
userID | grpID | name
----------------------
1      |1      | nick
2      |1      | john
3      |1      | florans
4      |1      | keit
5      |1      | maria
6      |2      | ian
7      |2      | george
8      |2      | peter
9      |2      | bill
10     |2      | jonathan
11     |3      | jenifer
12     |3      | mina
13     |3      | ben
14     |3      | nick
15     |3      | john
16     |4      | florans
17     |4      | keit
18     |4      | maria
19     |4      | ian
20     |4      | george
21     |5      | peter
22     |5      | bill
23     |5      | jonathan
24     |5      | jenifer
25     |5      | mina

table3:POSTS    
userID | posts
--------------
1      |  14
2      |  65
3      |  3
4      |  65
5      |  98
6      |  37
7      |  81
8      |  13
9      |  22
10     |  74
11     |  88
12     |  31
13     |  37
14     |  64
15     |  1
16     |  76
17     |  50
18     |  39
19     |  69
20     |  42
21     |  17
22     |  56
23     |  89
24     |  53
25     |  20
```

[**MySQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d59a0)

My goal is to get AVG (average) of the first 3 higher rows from every group. (or SUM of (max1, max2, max3) / 3 ). 
Something like this:

```
grpID | max1 | max2 | max3  | AVG of max1, max2, max3
---------------------------------------------------------
1       98      65      65      76
5       89      56      53      66
4       76      69      50      65
2       81      74      37      64
3       88      64      37      63
```

and display it ORDER BY first 3 average DESC.

The final result will be like this:

```
grpID  | first 3 higher rows Average
---------------------------------
1      |76
5      |66
4      |65
2      |64
3      |63
```

What i tried: (*** edited after Strawberry's comment)

```
SELECT GROUPS.grpID, GROUPS.name, AVG(POSTS.posts) AS PostsAVG
FROM USERS 
        INNER JOIN POSTS ON POSTS.userID = USERS.userID
        INNER JOIN GROUPS ON GROUPS.grpID = USERS.grpID
GROUP BY GROUPS.grpID
ORDER BY PostsAVG DESC
```

The result i am getting with this is

```
grpID  | name | PostsAVG
--------------------------------
4      |  D   | 55.2000
1      |  A   | 49.0000
5      |  E   | 47.0000
2      |  B   | 45.4000
3      |  C   | 44.2000
```

How can i get only the first three rows and not all 5 rows Average?
Can anyone help to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add a `LIMIT 3` to the end of your query?

Comment: you have to set limit 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display only top result from mysql query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28999451/display-only-top-result-from-mysql-query)

Comment: OK strawberry replace SUM with AVG (my mistake)...

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of variables to number the records in order of descending *posts*, per group. And then you could filter those on that row number ( `< 4` ) to finally average those per group:

```
select   grpid, avg(posts) as postavg
from     (   select  @rn := if(@grpid = grpid, @rn+1, 1) as rn,
                     @grpid := grpid as grpid, 
                     posts
             from    (  select      grpid, posts
                        from        users1 
                        inner join  posts1 
                                 on posts1.userid = users1.userid
                        order by    grpid, posts desc
                     ) ordered,
                     (  select @grpid := 0, @rn := 1) init
         ) numbered
where    rn < 4
group by grpid;
```

http://rextester.com/HWR28741

#### Without variables

Without variables (and without the availability of window functions), you'd probably do best to create a function for this:

```
create function GetAveragePosts (grpid int)
returns float
    return (select avg(posts)
            from   (    select      posts
                        from        users 
                        inner join  posts 
                                 on posts.userid = users.userid
                        where       users.grpid = grpid 
                        order by    posts desc
                        limit       3
                    ) topthree
    );
```

And then the SQL itself is straightforward:

```
select      grpid, 
            GetAveragePosts(grpid) as postsavg
from        users
group by    grpid
order by    2 desc
```

[MySql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43e61/1) outputs:

```
| grpID | postsavg |
|-------|----------|
|     1 |       76 |
|     5 |       66 |
|     4 |       65 |
|     2 |       64 |
|     3 |       63 |
```

Comment: Hello trincot. I dont know how to use variables.. i cant debug or update your code. I tried your query 
And the result set was
4 55.0000

5 54.0000

3 52.0000

2 43.6667

1 27.3333

not what i asked for in "The final result will be like this" paragraph :(
Thanks for your try..

Comment: Trincot your code works well in MySQL v5.6 (Works in fiddle), but didnt work in 10.1.13-MariaDB.. that i have installed here...
Anyway thanks for your response again.

Comment: Is there any way to have the same result without use of variables?

Comment: I added a solution which uses no variables.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you Trincot! Very nice try... Brilliant!